# Conditional factory

Tags: php, factory-method

I need to perform a payment and I have two payment methods: `FirstPayment` and `TokenPayment`, which both implement `PaymentInterface`

```
interface PaymentInterface
{
    public function pay(PaymentRequest $request);
}
```

According to a specific condition on `PaymentRequest` I need to choose whether to use `FirstPayment` of `TokenPayment`.

The client asking for the payment should not know which implementation to use.

I have two ideas regarding this.

1) I could have another implementation of `PaymentInterface` like

```
class Payment implements PaymentInterface
{
    public function pay(PaymentRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->isFirstPayment()) {
            $this->firstPayment->pay($request);
        } else {    
            $this->tokenPayment->pay($request);
        }
    }
}
```

where `$this->firstPayment` and `$this->tokenPayment` are instances of `FirstPayment` and `TokenPayment` respectively.

Hence the client could then simply do

```
$payment->pay($paymentRequest);
```

2) Have a factory

```
class PaymentFactory
{
    public static function choosePayment(PaymentRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->isFirstPayment()) {
            return new FirstPayment();
        }

        return new TokenPayment();
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
$payment = PaymentFactory::choosePayment($paymentRequest);
$payment->pay($paymentRequest);
```

In my opinion both options have some pros and cons... What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although for most cases the second approach is probably better, cases when you want to hide implementation details by retrieving a generic interface from a method by passing a flag (used to choose the correct implementation) and data to a factory, this seems more like a business rule and as such the first approach would be the go-to solution here.

The key here is to identify whether you are strictly introducing an abstraction or introducing a constraing to the code (perhaps from a user story), which has to be followed. In your case it's the latter and as such belongs to your business logic layer, not the place where object graph is constructed.